# How do I truncate a csv file?

Tags: csv

I have a csv file that is 6 gigabytes, but I don't need that much data, I need like 100 rows or so. How can I truncate it?

Comment: @K7AAY, sorry, I have no idea, that would require me to download the whole thing from s3 and check, which will take a while.

Comment: @K7AAY do csv files have '\n' at the end, should i just readline 100 times and write it to another file?

Comment: Windows and DOS use carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you want you can:

1. Take the 1st 100 rows [as suggested by @K7AAY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521773/22222).

   ```
   head -n100 filename.csv > file100.csv
   ```
2. Take the last 100 rows

   ```
   tail -n100 filename.csv > file100.csv
   ```
3. Take a random selection of 100 rows. This requires you have the GNU `shuf` program installed. It should be installable from your distribution's repositories if you're on Linux.

   ```
   shuf -n100 filename.csv > file100.csv
   ```

   Alternatively, if your `sort` supports the `-R` (random sort) option, you can do:

   ```
   sort -R filename.csv | head -n100 > file100.csv
   ```

Comment: What if one of the fields can contain newlines?

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge then you use a dedicated csv parser.

Answer (score 2):

Use [head](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-head/) to display only the first 100 lines and direct them to a new file. Please substitute the current file name for *filename.csv*:

```
head -n100 filename.csv > file100.csv
```